# I need to isolate the time from a date / timestamp

Tags: php, date, timestamp

I have a date string, or datestamp, whichever is the easiest.

The string looks like this:

```
Thursday, 01 December 2016 19:00 - 22:00
```

Or, if there is no end time:

```
Saturday, 01 December 2016 19:00
```

I can also get them as datestamps.

The `$event` object contains information like this:

```
[dtstart] => 1479232800 

[dtstart] => 1481094000 
[dtend] => 1481151599 
//apparently if there is no end time, the endtime is set to 23:59:59.
```

I tried doing this:

```
echo 'start '.date('H:i','$event->dtstart')
```

But that didn't give me anything.

Comment: PHP string basics: `date('H:i',$event->dtstart)`, `'` assumes a string as literal.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
echo 'start '.date('H:i','$event->dtstart');
```

to

```
echo 'start '.date('H:i',$event->dtstart);    // remove the quotes from 2 parameter and try again, it will give you the result like:
```

**start 10:00**

Answer (score 0):

> Remove quotes from $event->dtstart

```
 echo 'start '.date('H:i',$event->dtstart);   

example:  echo date('H:i',1171502725);
```